# Encrypted RSA Private KEY - What is this?

Tags: hashing, rsa

I'm new on cryptography and I have so many trouble to understand a lot of things.
On my screen, I use Openssl to generate RSA private key and I use DES3 to encrypt this private key.
Then I type my passphrase that is used "as a key" if I understand to encrypt my private key.
I have multiple question about this :

1. On my screen, what is the hexa code on the last line "60DB8..." ? What is it used for and how is it "created" ?
2. What is the mecanism that is Used to avoid same passpgrase giving the same key ? I guess it's something like my passphase is first encrypted, then we add a salt to it and then it's hashed?
3. If I want to use my private key, I have first to decrypt it with my passphrase (that is my key?). How does it procede to match my passphrase with my private key ?

[image]

Thank you a lot for your help and sorry for my mistakes

Answer (score 2):

> What is the hexa code on the last line "60DB8..." ? What is it used for and how is it "created" ?

It's a random value used as [Initialization Vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector) for the encryption of the private key. Displaying it is not the point of the `grep DEK`, which is to show `DES-EDE3-CBC`, that is the algorithm used for the encryption of the private key. For more on DEK-Info, see [RFC 1421 section 4.6.1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1421#section-4.6.1.3).

> What is the mechanism that is used to avoid same passphrase giving the same key?

The guess in the question is inaccurate. Actually, the private key (for public-key encryption and signature) is generated at random; and the passphrase is used to derive the secret key used to encipher the private key using symmetric-key cryptography.

With that arrangement, passphrase and private key are de-correlated. It's possible to change one or the other independently.

> If I want to use my private key, I have first to decrypt it with my passphrase (that is my key?). How does it proceed to match my passphrase with my private key?

Things are arranged so that using the wrong passphrase will most likely generate an error message.

In an ideal world, it would be used salt (the IV would do) and a purposely slow, amply parameterized password hashing/[key streching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching) function (such as [Argon2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2)) to transform the passphrase into the secret encryption key, then the decryption for the private key would be using some modern [authenticated encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption). That would make testing a dictionary of common passphrases as costly as possible for a bearable delay/cost at each legitimate use. But OpenSSL's key stretching is old and weak. The bottom line is that the passphrase should be complex to resist password search.

It might be that OpenSSL's authenticated encryption for private keys is rather ad-hoc, especially when using DES-EDE3-CBC; perhaps, on the tune of checking some constant field in the result of the decryption of the encrypted private key. That wouldn't have any damning consequence, since in the context we only want to resist accidental use of the wrong passphrase. I haven't dug the details.

Comment: There is no explicit authentication; it uses CBC with PKCS5/7 padding which catches 99.6% of mistakes (but not attacks), and the result must parse as an ASN.1 SEQUENCE (PKCS1 for RSA, SEC1/RFC5915 for EC, ad-hoc for DSA) which catches more. Note PKCS8 format files use PBKDF2 but still no authentication. PKCS12 (only) has password-based HMAC, but 'requires' a cert added to the privatekey. (Actually OpenSSL _can_ create a PKCS12 with key only, no cert(s), but it is likely not to work with other things.)

Comment: what does "and the passphrase is used to derive the secret key used to encipher the passphrase using symmetric-key cryptography." mean =(

Comment: @Minsky: that was plain an error. The second passphrase was supposed to be _private key_. I fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting, you're welcome. So if someone access my laptop and gets the secret key, they would still not be able to get the private key, unless they know my passphrase? I wrote it like this for myself: `openssl(passphrase, secret key, encripted private key)= plain private key`, but may be wrong interpretation.

Comment: @Minsly: Yes, that's right, when there's a passphrase to protect the private key (that's optional). Importantly, the derivation step is purposely slow, to make dictionary attacks harder. These try to enumerate possible passphrases and perform the operation in your equation.